# FQL or GraphSearch to query/grab All Public Items of a user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, web-crawler

Is there a way to query/get all of a user's items (status/ posts/ likes/ photos/ infos/ etc..) which are set as "public" visible?

I found something as below, for `like` for example:

```
SELECT object_id, post_id, user_id
FROM like
WHERE user_id = me()
```

But it is only for `myself` and also only `likes`.

Comment: Has the user granted the appropriate permissions? You still need permission if it's public data for a user. If it's a page rather than a user it's possible

Answer (score 1):

Your question too broad(get all items which was public?)

I can show you example related to public items, such as

```
SELECT post_id, privacy FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND privacy.value='EVERYONE'
```

Kindly take a look on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/privacy-parameter/ for privacy parameter tutorial.